# How to initialize my object array after deserialization

Tags: java, arrays, object, deserialization

Having two classes player and game. Implementing serialization and fileio. Serialization is working fine. Not able to get max length of the object array. I want the no of objects present in array.

```
class player {
  private String username;
}

class game {
  player array[] = new player[100];
  int arraysize;
  player player;

  public void setArraySize(int arraySize) {
    this.arraySize = arraySize;
  }

  public void readdata() { // reading from file starts
    //ObjectInputStream input = null;
    try {
      ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"));
      array = (NimPlayer[]) input.readObject();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    initializearraylength(array);
  }// reading file ends

  public void initializearraylength(NimPlayer[] temparray) {
    int size = temparray.length;
    setArraySize(size);
    System.out.println(size); // output displays size 100
  }
}
public display() {
  for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i].getusername());
  }
}
```

the variable arraySize is not initializing.I tried this code and getting a null pointer exception in readdata() firstline of try.

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at game.readdata(game.java:507)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace for the exception

Answer (score 1):

Your file is empty.

I don't know why you even have an `arraySize` variable if it's always going be the same as `array.length.` Just remove it. And you certainly don't need two methods to set it if you do keep it.

Comment: After removing those, I m getting the same error.
Its true that the file is empty because at the start there is nothing stored.

Comment: @Shivam If you didn't store anything at the start, there's probably not an object where you're reading from. You need to serialize an object first.

Comment: If there's nothing stored in the file why are you surprised at not getting anything out of it? This is not making any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The number of objects

```
  List<NimPlayer> tmp = Arrays.asList((NimPlayer[]) input.readObject());
  System.out.println(tmp.size());
```

For the error, change the declared variable int arraysize to arraySize

Comment: that is my writing mistake ignore that

Comment: @Shivam I forgot to ask you if you write all your array (NimPlayer[]) once or you write them successively (object = NimPlayer) to file.

Comment: @Shivam open your file "myfile.txt" and tell me if there is something inside even in binary.